# how many ways to add parentheses to make true statement

Tags: algorithm

Given string containing True and False, and also containing operators (and &, or ||, xor ^). How many ways to add parentheses to make the statement to be True?

```
Eg: Input T || F ^ F
(T||F)^F
T||(F^F)
(T||F^F)
output: 3
```

I encounter this question on the interview, I stuck into this, and didn't figure out. Very interesting question.

Any idea appreciated

Comment: `||` is logical xor, `|` is binary xor.  I assume you meant to use `||` in the sentence?

Comment: yes @MooingDuck and parenthesis must be used to disambiguate

Comment: Should we assume the precedence rules of C-based languages, or assume that parenthesis must be used to disambiguate?

Comment: @MooingDuck It only really affects how many states the DP has.

Comment: How to convert it to dp problem? @DavidEisenstat

Comment: If parenthesis must be used to disambiguate, the third option you list in the question is clearly illegal.

Comment: I assume we're not to add redundant parenthesis?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @zenith: I disagree.  I think he's asking "what's the algorithm for this problem", and the answer is "here's how to apply dynamic programming to this problem".

Comment: @SihanWang: Please rewrite the question to clarify these assumptions and to _actually ask a question_.

Comment: @SihanWang Right now you're asking "how many ways to place parentheses so the statement evaluates to true" which is unrelated to programming. Modify your post to add something programming-related to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Time to get out the sledgehammer known as [CYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) again. The parenthesizations correspond to distinct parses in a grammar like

```
Expr -> 'F'
      | 'T'
      | Expr '&' Expr
      | Expr '|' Expr
      | Expr '^' Expr
```

. We can write new rules for just true and just false expressions.

```
TExpr -> 'T'
       | TExpr '&' TExpr
       | TExpr '|' Expr
       | FExpr '|' TExpr
       | FExpr '^' TExpr
       | TExpr '^' FExpr

FExpr -> 'F'
       | FExpr '&' Expr
       | TExpr '&' FExpr
       | FExpr '|' FExpr
       | FExpr '^' FExpr
       | TExpr '^' TExpr
```

Then use CYK to count distinct parses.

More elaborate grammars handle the generalized problem where parenthesizes are optional and inferred by precedence.